# Где можно разместить видео файлы для приложения?

Tags: android, videoview

Для приложения необходимо использовать видео файлы (около 30) хранить в памяти не вариант. Подскажите где можно разместить их ? Подойдет ли облако для этого? Поделитесь ссылкой где можно об этом почитать.

Comment: можно в ютюбе

Comment: почему? там можно делать приватные видео и доступные только по ссылке

Comment: на дропБоксе, на собственном сервере

Comment: У меня по этой ссылке открывается страница с ошибкой 404 "Мы не нашли файл".

Comment: http://pomf.se/ попробуйте. Сразу выдаёт прямую ссылку, но меняет имя файла.

Comment: http://pomf.se/ - да действительно работает, но ресурс какой-то сомнительный... да еще и платный если больше 50Мб Может есть еще что нибудь И я не понимаю почему не работает ютуб и облачные хранилища ?

Comment: можно хранить на SD карте.

Comment: см. выше хранить в памяти не вариант.

Comment: >да еще и платный если больше 50Мб 

Я так понимаю, что самый очевидный вариант: просто завести свой хостинг - по каким-то непонятным причинам не катит? А зря.